# Is a spawned subprocess considered a new dyno on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, web, backgroundworker, flask

I just moved from Epio to Heroku and after reading about their new process model and I was wondering how Heroku handles subprocesses. The FAQ says [you can create subprocesses](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-faq#can_i_spawn_and_control_threads_and_subprocesses), but doesn't describe any of the implications of doing so.

Does each subprocess count as new a dyno that you have to pay for? If so, wouldn't using Gunicorn also get expensive since it pre-forks its subprocesses? Finally, since Heroku isolates its processes, how can you communicate with your subprocesses?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subprocesses are handled by a single dyno.

I'm not a python developer but I use Unicorn on my Heroku sites (Rails) usually with 4 subprocesses all contained within a single dyno. The amount of subprocesses you spawn needs to be mindful of memory consumption - you get 512Mb per dyno to play with.

Comment: So essentially, Heroku "processes" contain one or more machine processes and you can do whatever you need to as long as you're under 512 MB?

Comment: pretty much. I've seen people run unicorn and background tasks (via Resque) in the same dyno process. The 512Mb is a soft limit, you'll start getting R14 errors in your log files once you go over that, after that the process will start swapping to disk and then if you get up to 1.5Gb you'll get R15 errors.